# Gettext can't get setlocale() to work

Tags: php, localization, gettext

I use gettext localization like this

```
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
echo $lang;
putenv("LANG=$lang"); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang); 
bindtextdomain("messages", realpath("../locale")); 
bind_textdomain_codeset("messages", "utf-8"); 
textdomain("messages"); 

... 

echo _("Welcome!") etc.
```

I can see localization works, because the site can be seen translated in Slovak. However, no mather what is in the $lang variable, the site only is translated in Slovak or not translated at all.

Slovak means whatever .po and .mo files i have in 'sk' folder. I have tried putting different languages in the 'sk' folder, it works and I get different translations. But I cannot make it to take different folder, like 'en' or 'cs'. All other folders are ignored. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. setlocale() returns false, I can't figure out why but that's probably causing the trouble.

Comment: Did you take a look at the comments in http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php?

Comment: well I did and I don't see a solution there, I've tried renaming both folder and $lang variable to en_US, I still got the 'sk' translation.

Comment: If I have to guess your standard locale is sk and that is what it uses because the locale change never happens. You point out your setlocale call returns false. What are you passing it? What's the contents of `$lang`?

Comment: I have tried 'cs', 'en', 'en_US', 'en_US.utf8'. All folders with such names are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setlocale()` will return false if your system does not support that locale. You can see which locales your system supports by examining the output of `locale -a`. The value that you pass in via the lang get var must match one of those locale names.

As Dan says, sk is probably your standard locale which is why that is used even if setlocale returns false..

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is another nasty hack:

On my system only en_DK.utf-8 is install and I'm not able to install any other langs.

So, i'm selecting the language by using the domain instead:

```
$lang = "en";
putenv("LANG=en_DK.utf8"); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_DK.utf8");
bindtextdomain($lang, realpath("./locale")); 
bind_textdomain_codeset($lang, "utf-8"); 
textdomain($lang);
```

The file location of the .mo files are like this:

```
./locale/en_DK.utf-8/LC_MESSAGES/en.mo
```